# Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[x86_64] Bare React Native Error

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-core-modules

I am trying to run a React Native application on Android device. Although, Gradle build finishes successfully, but, the app does not build or run. It keeps giving me this weir error:

```
> Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[armeabi-v7a]
C/C++: ninja: Entering directory `/Users/abc/Documents/React_Native_Apps/app-new/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/.cxx/Debug/131e2i41/armeabi-v7a'
C/C++: In file included from /Users/abc/Documents/React_Native_Apps/app-new/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp:3:
C/C++: In file included from /Users/abc/Documents/React_Native_Apps/app-new/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.h:5:
C/C++: In file included from /Users/abc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/af481f74ca2b61c91496ce7d7a53c1e7/transformed/jetified-fbjni-0.3.0/prefab/modules/fbjni/include/fbjni/fbjni.h:21:
C/C++: In file included from /Users/abc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/af481f74ca2b61c91496ce7d7a53c1e7/transformed/jetified-fbjni-0.3.0/prefab/modules/fbjni/include/fbjni/detail/Environment.h:18:
C/C++: In file included from /Users/abc/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:504:
C/C++: /Users/abc/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:4434:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'is_constructible<facebook::react::LongLivedObjectCollection>::value' "Can't construct object in make_shared"
C/C++: /Users/abc/Documents/React_Native_Apps/app-new/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp:238:37: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::make_shared<facebook::react::LongLivedObjectCollection>' requested here
C/C++: In file included from /Users/abc/Documents/React_Native_Apps/app-new/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp:3:
C/C++: In file included from /Users/abc/Documents/React_Native_Apps/app-new/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.h:5:
C/C++: In file included from /Users/abc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/af481f74ca2b61c91496ce7d7a53c1e7/transformed/jetified-fbjni-0.3.0/prefab/modules/fbjni/include/fbjni/fbjni.h:21:
C/C++: In file included from /Users/abc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/af481f74ca2b61c91496ce7d7a53c1e7/transformed/jetified-fbjni-0.3.0/prefab/modules/fbjni/include/fbjni/detail/Environment.h:18:
C/C++: In file included from /Users/abc/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:504:
C/C++: /Users/jasminderpalsingh/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2260:46: error: field of type 'facebook::react::LongLivedObjectCollection' has private default constructor
C/C++: /Users/abc/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2353:42: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__compressed_pair_elem<facebook::react::LongLivedObjectCollection, 1, false>::__compressed_pair_elem' requested here
C/C++: /Users/abc/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:3628:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__compressed_pair<std::allocator<facebook::react::LongLivedObjectCollection>, facebook::react::LongLivedObjectCollection>::__compressed_pair<std::allocator<facebook::react::LongLivedObjectCollection>, std::__value_init_tag>' requested here
C/C++: /Users/abc/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:4441:26: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__shared_ptr_emplace<facebook::react::LongLivedObjectCollection, std::allocator<facebook::react::LongLivedObjectCollection>>::__shared_ptr_emplace' requested here
C/C++: /Users/abc/Documents/React_Native_Apps/app-new/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp:238:37: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::make_shared<facebook::react::LongLivedObjectCollection>' requested here
C/C++: /Users/abc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/05f8c5110695b559e432038ccd78233f/transformed/jetified-react-android-0.72.0-debug/prefab/modules/react_nativemodule_core/include/react/bridging/LongLivedObject.h:52:3: note: declared private here
C/C++: /Users/abc/Documents/React_Native_Apps/app-new/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/cpp/MethodMetadata.cpp:40:57: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 3, have 4
C/C++: /Users/abc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/05f8c5110695b559e432038ccd78233f/transformed/jetified-react-android-0.72.0-debug/prefab/modules/react_nativemodule_core/include/react/bridging/CallbackWrapper.h:34:41: note: 'createWeak' declared here

> Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[armeabi-v7a] FAILED
```

There are other similar errors for [x86] and [x86_64].
Another error that I am seeing is in MethodMetadata.cpp:

```
/Users/abc/Documents/React_Native_Apps/app-new/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/cpp/MethodMetadata.cpp:40:57: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 3, have 4
/Users/abc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/05f8c5110695b559e432038ccd78233f/transformed/jetified-react-android-0.72.0-debug/prefab/modules/react_nativemodule_core/include/react/bridging/CallbackWrapper.h:34:41: note: 'createWeak' declared here
```

I have tried deleting node_modules, clearing cache, ./gradlew clean, every such thing, but, nothing has worked so far.

I am using:
"expo": "^48.0.0",
"react-native": "~0.72.0",
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1(Tried with Patch 2 too)
Device: Macbook M2 Pro

Comment: I have the same issue. I have also tried deleting `~/.gradle/caches`, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to upgrade expo to SDK 49 (and any other expo libraries), or later as mentioned in the [react-native release notes](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/06/21/0.72-metro-package-exports-symlinks#upgrade-to-072)

> If you use Expo, React Native version 0.72 will be supported in the Expo SDK 49 release.

In my case, I had to update both `expo` and `expo-modules-core` to fix this build error

```bash
npm install expo@latest
npm install expo-modules-core@latest # if you use it
```

```bash
yarn add expo@latest
yarn add expo-modules-core@latest # if you use it
```

Comment: Yes, most likely. At that time, expo 49 had not come out, so, I switched to RN 0.71.8. That worked. Haven’t tried upgrading RN now with Expo 49

Comment: @KaranveerSingh gotcha, well since you're the first to ask this question it would still be important for this solution to be known for anyone else who may encounter the issue

Comment: I can’t really test it right now as the project is in crucial stage. But, I will create a new one and test it as soon as I can

Comment: Hey, the same is happening to me. I'm using "react-native": "0.71.3" and "expo": "~48.0.17",
For me, the build was working fine. But after updating my patch files it is not working with this issue.
Any suggestion for me?